# Mysql table: Insert a column with ascending numbers (1 to [total number of rows]) in the order of the datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime

Mysql: I have a table with an ID column (primary key), datetime column and others. Let's say 1000 rows.
I don't want to change the ID but add another column and fill it with counts from 1 to 1000 in a way that the row with the earliest datetime gets "1", the second "2" ... and the latest gets "1000".

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Strawberry already asked, why? The only reason I can think of that makes sense in some way, is, that you eventually want to replace your current primary key, but even this is not necessary. And you should avoid storing redundant data. When the order of the rows is already determined with the datetime column, there's no need to introduce a second column to do just that.

Anyway, here's how you can do that. First add your new column.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN new_column int;
```

In the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) for the `UPDATE` syntax you got this:

> Single-table syntax:
>
> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
>     SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY ...]
>     [LIMIT row_count]
> ```

So you just need to initialize a variable and update your table while incrementing it.

```
SET @my_increment := 0;
UPDATE your_table 
SET new_column = @my_increment := @my_increment + 1
ORDER BY your_datetime_column;
```

Comment: Now, why adding the new column?
First, that's right, it's a going to replace the old ID (PK). The table will be a "pattern table" for some use in the future and it seems much nicer, not to have a "wild" order of the IDs. And not only "nicer" but also "safer" as I might use the table in let's say two years without remembering that the ID has nothing to do with the order of the datetime (although it seems in my case). And I don't have any relations with other tables.

Comment: Second, I have to do a lot of queries with 3 consecutive rows and I am not sure if it's that simple with the datetime format as with id-1 and id+1

Comment: I tried to vote for your answer but it stays 0. Why?

Comment: That's because you have not enough reputation yet. Here's a [quick guide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) how this site works.